# Is there a more efficient alternative to find an object with a to-one relationship to two objects I have?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, core-data, entity-relationship

I have the following Core Data setup:

```
Project has-many Answer
Field has-many Answer
Answer has-one Field
Answer has-one Project
```

I need to find the Answer for each Field that is also owned by Project.  I'm currently using a predicate for this and executing a fetch request:

```
NSEntityDescription *answerEntity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Answer" inManagedObjectContext:self.managedObjectContext];
NSPredicate *answerPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"ANY project == %@ && field == %@", self.project, self.field];          
NSFetchRequest *answerRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
[answerRequest setEntity:answerEntity];
[answerRequest setPredicate:answerPredicate];

NSError *error = nil;
NSArray *predicates = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:answerRequest error:&error];
```

I'm still new to Core Data but I believe the fetchRequest is querying the database each time I call it, is there a more efficient way of finding these Answer objects?

Comment: Not sure if the ANY is needed there. The only other thing would be to reverse the project and field if the field is more rare or the number of fields is drastically smaller.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I'm sure there is a design pattern i'm missing here because if I have 50 fields, 50 projects and 50 answers (i'll likely have many more than this) the app will run 50 queries when rendering a UITableView

Comment: Clarification: You need to find all the Answer objects owned by a particular Field object as well as a particular Project object?

Comment: Yes, exactly.  The code above and the answer I posted below work properly, i'm just looking for the correct (efficient) way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you already have a Field object and an Project object and you want to find the Answer objects they have in common.

If so, the solution is a simple intersect set operation:

```
NSSet *answersInCommon=[[aFieldObj mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"] intersectSet:[aProjectObj mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];
```

... which will return only those Answer objects that appear in both relationships.

### Update:

@pdenya in comment provides an enhancement :

Just want to clarify a minor error and a small point that makes this less than ideal. intersectSet returns (void) so the syntax for this would be:

```
NSMutableSet *answers=[field mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]; 
[answers intersectSet:[project mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];
```

This solution also modifies the aFieldObj.answers array meaning you can't use this while iterating. setWithSet clears this right up. Example:

```
NSMutableSet *answers = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:[project mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]]; 
[answers intersectSet:[field mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];
```

@pdenya's is the correct form.

Comment: Just want to clarify a minor error and a small point that makes this less than ideal.

intersectSet returns (void) so the syntax for this would be:
NSMutableSet *answers=[field mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"];
[answers intersectSet:[project mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];

This solution also modifies the aFieldObj.answers array meaning you can't use this while iterating.  setWithSet clears this right up.  Example:
NSMutableSet *answers = [NSMutableSet setWithSet:[project mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];
[answers intersectSet:[field mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"]];

Comment: Yes, you are correct. I will edit. to many APIs and languages jostling around in my head.

Answer (score 0):

Best alternate method I've found so far:

```
NSMutableSet *answers = [self.project mutableSetValueForKey:@"answers"];
NSPredicate *answerPredicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"field == %@", field];
[answers filterUsingPredicate:answerPredicate];

NSManagedObject *answer = nil;
if([answers count] > 0) {
    answer = [[answers allObjects] objectAtIndex:0];
}
```